# Can I prevent amqp.Channel closing on errors?

Tags: go, rabbitmq

I try to create multiple AMQP queue consumers on a single channel in Go.

The problem I am facing is that when creating multiple consumers, if the first fails, the channel gets closed right away, preventing further operations.

Is there a way to avoid this or do I have to re-create the channel?

### Example

Assuming that the queue "client-a" does not exist, this will result in an error when creating a queue consumer for "client-b" because the channel has been closed at that point. The error would be `Exception (504) Reason: "channel/connection is not open"`

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
    "log"
)

func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func TestChannelProblems() {
    // Setup AMQP stuff
    connection, err := amqp.Dial("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/")
    check(err)
    log.Println("Queue connection ok")

    channel, err := connection.Channel()
    check(err)
    log.Println("Queue channel ok")

    queuesToConnectTo := []string{"client-a", "client-b"}

    for i, _ := range queuesToConnectTo {
        queueName := queuesToConnectTo[i]

        _, err := channel.Consume(queueName, "", false, false, false, false, nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Connecting to queue %v failed: %v", queueName, err.Error())
        }

        // ... Here would be the logic to use the return value of channel.Consume
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the channel closed? Please show a [mre]

Comment: Will do, might take a monent. Sorry for missing that

Comment: Done. I am sure there is a way to handle this scenario myself by coding some resilient solution. What I am asking my self is if there is a way to have RabbitMQ not close the channel on exceptions like this one

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. `Channel.Consume` itself returns a read-only channel of `Delivery`, which in turn can be read of for new messages. So you want the same connection to handle multiple queues? And what prevents you from using `Channel.QueueDeclare`, as suggested in the documentation?

Comment: Using `QueueDeclare` would of course be the correct option. Sadly I am not in control of that since my software is just a minor part of a monolithic system where the queues may not be created by me... *sigh*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short: channels being closed on protocol exceptions is a normal behaviour in AMQP (or RabbitMQ at least) and must be dealt with by the application.

Source: https://www.rabbitmq.com/channels.html#error-handling

Answer (score 0):

> I try to create multiple amqp queue consumers on a single channel in Go.

This is generally not recommended. If one of your consumers encounters an error, it will shut down the other two as well. You should open one channel for each consumer. Even though opening a channel is relatively costly, as it is a network roundtrip, this is unlikely to become an issue in practice.

> Is there a way to prevent this or do I have to re-create the channel?

You have to recreate the channel. The library `streadway/amqp` closes the delivery channel anyway (channel = the Go type `<-chan amqp.Delivery`) if any error occurs on the connection.

You can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991926/how-to-detect-dead-rabbitmq-connection) for details about how to handle AMQP errors and possibly recover them. In essence, you use [`NotifyClose`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/streadway/amqp#Channel.NotifyClose) to listen for close events:

```
// c is an *amqp.Channel
errC := c.NotifyClose(make(chan *amqp.Error, 10))
go func() {
    for err := range errC {
        if err != nil {
            // error-handling
        }
    }
}()
```